# How can I make sure its enough disk space in batch?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, diskspace

Does anyone know if its possible to make sure the disk has enough space on a server with batch?

I have a batch script that loops and in this I would like to add a part that makes sure there is enough space on the disk and gives me an message if its not. Like this, easily explained:

```
Check diskspace
 If below 10mb free space
  echo low diskspace (& probably delete temp files or something)
   else continue
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the output of the `dir` command to retrieve the free space. All the test is wapped inside a subroutine that receives as argument the "drive" to check and the number of bytes required. On exit it raises errorlevel when there is no enough free space.

Arithmetic in batch files is limited 2^31 signed integers, so to handle values greater than 2147483647 and operate with storage units over 2GB more code is required. To avoid this, all the information is indicated/retrieved in bytes, padded and compared as strings.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :checkFreeSpace d: 123456789 && echo OK || echo No space

    call :checkFreeSpace "\\10.0.0.1\c$" 2000000000
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo No space
    ) else (
        echo OK
    )

    goto :eof

:checkFreeSpace drive spaceRequired
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "pad=0000000000000000000000000"
    set "required=%pad%%~2"
    for %%d in ("%~1\.") do for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('
        dir /a /-c "%%~fd" 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /l /c:"  " 
    ') do set "freeSpace=%pad%%%a"
    if "%freeSpace:~-25%" geq "%required:~-25%" exit /b 0
    exit /b 1
```

**note**: This method has one caveat. If the indicated target is a drive root and there is not any file/folder in it, the `dir` command will not found anything to list and the free space will not be included in its output, making the test fail as the free space will be 0

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the great answer. Knownledge right there! Tho I must admit I'm having some issues making it work. I'm probably at a new beginner stage. I think my first issue will be how the call :checkfreespace command works. Do I need something else with the script?

Comment: @Excessium, the posted code shows usage. The easiest way is to copy/paste the subroutine at the end of your batch file and call it from your code as show in the sample.

Comment: Ah alright, I appreciate your help.  I will give it a try and do my best tomorrow. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having some issues to understand the whole script. I think I get the basics after your explanation, but I try to figure out where to edit what for my purpose. 

I set everything below ":checkFreeSpace drive spaceRequired" in the bottom of the script and everything above in the part of my script where I want to check if enough free space on disk.

How can I specify if it has to be at least 5% free space? I tried to change up this line "%freeSpace:~-25%" geq "%required:~-25%", but it seems it doesnt work... Sometimes it exits, sometimes it get "OK" echo and then exit.

Comment: @Excessium, as indicated in the answer, the posted code works only on size (bytes in this case). To operate with percents it is necessary to first know the size of the volume, without a lot more information this can not be done. The expresion `%freeSpace:~-25%` is taking 25 characters from the right of the padded string contained in the variable `%freeSpace%` to compare against the required space (also the rightmost 25 characters from a padded string)

Comment: Ah ok, now it makes sense to me. Thanks for explaining it to me! I'll see what I can do with it in my purpose, although I understand now that its a little limited. Have a great day!